# Inconsistency experienced in downloading a web page

Tags: powershell-2.0, webclient

I have been experiencing some inconsistency with the way a web page gets downloaded using PowerShell.

This is the script:

```psh
$url2 = ("webpageurl")
$credentials = Get-Credential
$webobj = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$webobj.credentials = $credentials
$content=$webobj.downloadstring($url2)
$content
```

Here `webpageurl` is an internal webpage that takes a different credentials other than the one with which I login in to my PC.

When I run the above script, some time the webpage gets downloaded and sometimes it just fails with the following error.

```
Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The remote server
returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."
At C:\Users\schandras_adm\Documents\windowspowershell\get-ndswebpage.ps1:6 char:32
+ $content=$webobj.downloadstring <<<< ($url2)
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

For example, if I run this say 6 times it works, the 7th time and 8th time it may fail again, and so on.

I am just confused as to why it fails sometimes and sometimes it works without any change in the script or the credentials.

Comment: Can you test this with another account ? Can you make a loop and maybe try to iterate 100 or 1000 times to see if there is some kind of pattern ? Is there another page on the same site with no authentication so you can confirm it works flawlessly ?